# Adwords Api get click data + keywords

Tags: google-ads-api

Is it possible to use the glcid supplied from Ad words to pull data from the AdWords API?

In particular I would be looking for cost of a click and the keywords used to search for the advert.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generaly, you can use GCLID in API, for example when importing offline conversions after conversion happened and you somehow saved GCLID. **Unfortunately, in Keywords report, passing GCLID parameter as argument is not supported.**

[Using Gclid for import](https://developers.google.com/adwords/api/docs/guides/importing-conversions)

[Keywords performance report](https://developers.google.com/adwords/api/docs/appendix/reports/keywords-performance-report)

Comment: Well that is bit rubbish! I have offline conversions that happen, so will need to upload them, but also have conversions that are nothing to do with adwords, would be good to be able to see them all in one place.